# Issue with python lists and loops

Tags: python

I am starting to learn python, and playing around with loops and lists.
I can't understand how this doesn't continue till printing "The end"

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
for n in x:
    if len(x) > 0:
        x.pop(0)
        print(x)
    else:
        break
        print("The end")
```

I get:

```
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4]
```

Comment: Put the `break` after the `print`

Comment: It is because `break` let's the program go leave the for-loop without executing any line after it (the print line). place the `print("The end")` in front of `break`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two bigger issues here.

1. Don't modify an iterable as you loop over it. This makes the execution extremely difficult to rationalize about and can cause a lot of weird behavior.
2. You put a `break` before the `print`. The `break` statement will exit the loop before you reach the `print` line.

Instead I would perform this action with a `while` loop, and do the end condition after the loop:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
while len(x) > 0:
    x.pop(0)
    print(x)
print("The end")
```

```
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4]
[4]
[]
The end
```